# Can a call be initiated in the same group as chat in Azure Communication Services

Tags: .net, azure, react-redux

We are trying to integrate Group Chat and Calling application in Azure Communication service. We want users to initiate a Call in the same group in which the group chat is in the process without sharing the groupId for the call application. How do we achieve this?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

At this stage Azure Communication Services does not support calling a chat conversation directly. In the meantime, the recommendation would be to programmatically call the identifiers of the members of chat threads.

[Initialize the chat thread client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-javascript)

```
let threadMembers = [];
for await (let page of chatThreadClient.listMembers().byPage()) {
  for (const threadMember of page) {
    threadMembers.push(threadMember);
  }
}
let ids = threadMembers.filter((threadMember) => threadMember.user);
```

[Initialize call agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/getting-started-with-calling?pivots=platform-web)

```
callAgent.call(ids);
```